# Loop through and Update each row of an sql table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop

I'm trying to make a quick lil' script to just add some dummy data to a new column I added to a database table I have, the table has 1000 entries so doing it by hand isn't really an option.

What I have right now it:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); mysql_select_db('cdb', $conn);                      

$string = "4050605040302030405060708070304050403040506070605040302010203040506070655545352515756535243515353545"; //50 values
$mpgsplit = str_split($string, 2);

for ($i=0; $i<=20; $i++)
{
    for ($x=0; $x<=50; $x++)
    {$r = mysql_query  ("UPDATE cars SET mpg = '".$mpgsplit[$x]."'", $conn);}
}
?>
```

Issue being using update doesn't work as it just replaces the value of every row of that column with each number every time it loops. For me it reached number 48 in the array and timed out.

Then using insert just makes all new rows.

So I need a way to cycle through each row and update it.

The nearest I've been to looping through and dealing with singular rows of a table is this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imported_orders");
$orderNo = $_POST['orderNo'];
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
if($orderNo>0&&$orderNo<=count($row))
{
    $file = fopen('Order.txt', 'w');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
```

But thats just taking the row as a variable, not sure if I can translate that to what I need.

Theres probably a simple function out there which does this, but I've tried searching and can't find it. Theres also probably an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do overall as well, so that would be welcome.

All help much appreciated. -Tom

Answer (score 0):

Issue this sql statement directly in mysql command line or from a php script.

```
SET @r := 0;
UPDATE  cars
SET     mpg = (@r := @r + 1)
ORDER BY
        RAND()
```

This sql statement will assign number from 0 till Total row count of your db to a random row. I guess it might be helpful

Comment: Not sure how but this has just made me realise the table has a primary key which is just 1-1000 so I can just add a WHERE clause to my sql based on the loop number.

Its been so long since I've touched php and sql I completely forgot about primary keys.